# how to make list of widget from button

Tags: flutter

i want to make a column contains widgets show up when i click on a buttun
it is like a logo when i click on it show a list contains drawer components
i tried this way but it did not work propably

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: PopupMenuButton(
            // position: null,
            itemBuilder: (context) => [
              PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text("onre"),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100)),
              PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text("onre"),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100)),
              PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text("onre"),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100)),
              PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text("onre"),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100)),
              PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text("onre"),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100)),
            ],
            child: Text("data"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}ype here
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must make every `PopupMenuItem` unique.

```
itemBuilder: (context) => [
          PopupMenuItem(
              child: Text("one"),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100)),
          PopupMenuItem(
              child: Text("two"),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100)),
          PopupMenuItem(
              child: Text("three"),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100)),
          PopupMenuItem(
              child: Text("four"),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100)),
          PopupMenuItem(
              child: Text("five"),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100)),
        ]
```